# Group by dates range mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've got this collection in the db

```
[{name:1,startDate:1/1/13,endDate:2/2/13,number:10},
{name:1,startDate:2/2/13,endDate:5/2/13,number:15},
{name:2,startDate:2/1/13,endDate:5/2/13,number:25},
{name:1,startDate:5/2/13,number:17},
{name:2,startDate:5/2/13,number:30}]
```

I want to get a list of start dates with the average of the number within the range of this start date, for example, the result of this collection would be:

```
{date:1/1/13,avg:10},
{date:2/1/13,avg:17.5},
{date:2/2/13,avg:20},
{date:5/2/13,avg:23.5}
```

I've tried some map-reduce and group but none can group by start date properly,
please help.

Comment: Can you explain more how you calculated that avg.

Comment: The first result is 10 because in 1/1/13 there is no other dates involved

Comment: The second is 17.5 because the first item in the collection and the third are in the 2/1/13 date

Comment: Is this an ok explanation?

Comment: explanation good, but you should edit your question because in first documnets 2/1/13 date not present?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make logical sense. Why would there not be an "average" for "3/2/13" and "4/2/13" and so on. You are being far too selective here and I actually believe your logic to be basically wrong.

Comment: There is an average in the continuing dates but it's irrelevant because it will be the same and if the dates spread over years i don't want to get hundreds of answers...
The only changes are in the start dates so i want to group by them.

Comment: @user1918845 I can't figure out your logic. How are you defining the range of dates to group by?

Comment: That's the problem, a friend sent me a map reduce function, it seems correct, I'll try it out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the aggregation pipleline:

db.collectionName.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$startDate',avg:{$avg:'$number'}}}])

This will group the collection by startDate and with the aggregation being the average of the number.

If you strictly want the _id field labelled as startDate, you use the $project operation in the pipeline:

db.collectionName.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'$startDate', avg:{$avg:'$number'}}},{$project:{'startDate':'$_id','avg':'$avg',_id:0}}])

This will give the desired result.

Comment: No it does not. Perhaps you should have read the comments given. "2/1/13" cannot produce 17.5 as was asked because that is not a "start_date"

Comment: Sorry, not what i meant,
this doesn't get the answer... i'm looking for the average of number in a range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better way i just did it from the server side,

first getting all the startDate s and then preforming an iteration that finds every document in the date range and averaging it's number...

Not quit how i expected to solve this, but it works properly.